# r grepl to distinguish between no and not

Tags: r, string, grepl

I am dealing with two strings like this below

```
      x1 <- "Unknown, because not discussed"

      x2 <- "Not at goal, no."
```

How do i use grepl function to distinguish between these two strings ?

When I use  `grepl("no", x1)`, it shows TRUE, which is not correct. This is picking up the no in `not` or `Unknown`. How do i use string parsing function to detect strings with the word `no` explicitly ? Any advise is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use word boundary `\\b` to distinguish them. `\\bno\\b` will match `no` only without preceding and following word characters:

```
grepl("\\bno\\b", x1)
# [1] FALSE
grepl("\\bno\\b", x2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

I can think of a couple of options for matching "no" but not "not":

Using the `\b` "word boundary" pattern:

```
> x = c("Unknown, because not discussed", "Not at goal, no.")
> grepl("\\bno\\b", x)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Using `[^t]` to exclude "not":

```
> grepl("\\bno[^t]", x)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

For matching the word "no" by itself the word boundary option `"\\bno\\b"` is probably best.